Does one have to follow the meters present in a Vedic stotra?
For any Vedic stotra does one have to properly follow the syllable and meter to get any results?

No Vedic mantra can exist if Chandha is dropped ! Thus, yes meters and syllables must be chanted very properly. There are many verses where meanings change if dirgaswara is replaced by shorter one, or if Chandha is broken abruptly, or if sandhi is broken due to aforementioned reasons! Even, as speeds of recitation changes various changes take place is swaras, and thus learning under a qualified Guru is must!
